# Databinding to show an assembly name

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a ComboBox of assemblies, and I would like to only display the assembly Name, as opposed to the FullName. The equivalent code of what I want to do in the binding is

```
 asm.GetName().Name
```

I'm tagging this as a c# question also since maybe there is a property on Assembly I don't know about.

Here is the relevant part of the XAML I am using:

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}" /> ** just the Name please
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

What's a good way to do this?

Cheers,
Berry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a [value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) which will call GetName method and return Name.

```
public class AssemblyNameConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var assembly = (Assembly)value;
        return assembly.GetName().Name;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a case you can bind combobox to a dictionary, where Key would be an assembly name and Value - assembly itself so you would be able bind to assembly name and other properties as well.

```cs
allAssembliesMap.Add(assembly.GetName().Name, assembly);

public IDictionary<string, Assembly> AllAssemblies 
{ 
    get 
    { 
       return allAssembliesMap; 
    } 
}
```

```xml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllAssemblies}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Key"
          SelectedValuePath="Value" />
```